# Select rows that have different values for a column, given another column

Tags: sql

Given a table with 2 columns a, b.

I want to select rows that for a given a, I can have different values of b.

In this example, I want the first 2 lines

```
a | b
-----
1 | 1  
1 | 2 
2 | 1
2 | 1
3 | 1
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM mytable AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT a
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY a
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT b) > 1
) AS t2 ON t1.a = t2.a
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention your DBMS, but in Oracle you can do:

```
select a,b
from (
  select a,b, 
         count(distinct b) over (partition by a) as num_b
  from the_table
) t
where num_b > 1
```

Unfortunately Postgres or SQL Server do not support `distinct` for window functions.